# How can I allow macchanger to run on ubuntu touch/apparmor?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, apparmor

I'm trying to run macchanger from the terminal application of an ubuntu touch device to avoid unscrupulous 3rd parties(i.e. wifi providers) from tracing my mac address. However it fails miserably with the error below: (the current mac XX is masked on purpose)

```
/home/phablet# macchanger -e ccmni0
[ERROR] Could not read permanent MAC: Operation not supported
Current MAC:   XX:XX:34:v7:66:f8 (unknown)
Permanent MAC: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (XEROX CORPORATION)
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Operation not supported
```

I've tried to find the apparmor permissions required by macchanger with no success.Any idea how can be fixed?

Edit: I've tried to run the command from adb shell with the same result so I'm not sure anymore if it's an issue with apparmor or ubuntu touch distro.

I've also tried `ip link set dev ccmni0 address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:` and got

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

Edit:
I've  reinstalled macchanger (apt-get install macchanger). During the installation I've got a question ("....do you want to generate a random mac address on each reboot") -select -> Yes. Now the mac changes on reboot but I'm still unable to change it on runtime (without a reboot).

Comment: Does the hardware support MAC changing?

Comment: How can I know that? For what it's worth is a mobile device ( https://github.com/bq/aquaris-E4.5 )

Comment: 1. Find and read the hardware description; 2. Try it with the interface down, like the error message says.

Comment: I've actually tried that too    `ip link set dev ccmni0 down` `ip link set dev ccmni0 address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`  ` ip link set dev ccmni0 up` with no success